# HELP SharePoint 2016 farm is completely down

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem

I am currently experiencing an unknown error. every single site i visit says sorry something went wrong. when i look up the correlation code I am unable to find it in my URL log.

Answer (score 1):

Without much details I cannot say what went wrong. You can try below:

1. Check the DNS and Load Balancer configuration
2. Check if the SharePoint Timer Service is started
3. Verify that the SharePoint Servers are able to connect to the database
4. Check free space on the drive.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the event-log on the server?
Service account password changed?
Use PowerShell to get the most relevant events.
`Merge-SPLogFile -Path "C:\tmp\FarmMergedLog.log" -Level High`

Answer (score 0):

Did you refer to your ULS logs? The default location for SharePoint 2016 ULS logs is `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\Logs`. You can use ULS Log Viewer to analyze SharePoint errors like filtering by correlation ID. Reference: [How to Use ULS Log Viewer to Analyze SharePoint Errors?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/08/how-to-use-uls-viewer-in-sharepoint-to-analyse-errors.html)
Could you find any clues in your ULS logs? It's hard to troubleshoot such issue without any details.